# Running JS function for a different ID variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to get my ajax function to run twice, for two different forms. I made the bit of code into a function now I don't know how I can run it for a different form id.

That line of code is var form = $('#home-form'); That's the first form the second form has an id of 'popup-form'.

After pasting it here too, I noticed that the modal after the form sends would re-open. What would you suggest for this to only run when the first form is sent?

Here is the function...

```
function formAjax() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#home-form');
    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');

            // Pop-up Second Form
            $("#sendForm").modal();

        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occurred and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });
    });
}
formAjax();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var forms = $('#home-form, #popup-form');
```

then you may want to do something like

```
$.each(forms, function(){
  $(this).submit(function(e){
     // submit logic here
  });
});
```